# How to prevent git from staging deleted files with git add .?

Tags: git, staging

I was trying to stage multiple files for a react-app I'm building and after staging the project files with `git add .` I then run `git status` and it shows that I staged files that I had previously deleted. I found out that git changed and that `git add .` stages deleted files now so I'm looking for a command that will only stage current files (and not these deleted files).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git add --ignore-removal .
```

> `--ignore-removal`
>
> Update the index by adding new files that are unknown to the index and files modified in the working tree, but ignore files that have been removed from the working tree.

[git-add Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add)

Comment: Nice it worked. One last question. How can I get rid of those deleted files. Even though they are no longer getting added to the commit, they still showing up as 'files not staged for commit' when i run git status. I don't want them to show up at all anymore.

Comment: @Jesse You need to stage the deletions! Deleting a file will show in `git status` as a file deletion, so if you don't commit the fact that you've deleted the file it won't be deleted for anyone else, and if you ‘remove’ the deletions that will ‘undo’ the deletion and put the file back!